# SUMIF formula for months

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

How can I do if I want to sum a specific range depending on what month it is. So if the month in a range is the same as todays month, then i want it to sum a range.

I have this code

```
=IF(TEXT(TODAY();"MMMM")=A:A; SUMIF($B:$B;"X*"; C:C); "")
```

'SUMIF($B:$B;"X*"; C:C); "")` this is working fine, but if i put the "if" before then nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$1000)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(LEFT($B$1:$B$1000,1)="X"),$C$1:$C$1000)
```

Note: don't use entire column references with SUMPRODUCT like this. This assumes you only want to match on month and not year as well.

You could also use SUMIFS if you want to match on year too:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,">"&TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),$A:$A,"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1),$B:$B,"X*")
```

Edit: if column A is just the month name as text, then use

```
=SUMIFS($BD:$BD,$A:$A,text(TODAY(),"mmmm"),$BC:$BC,"X*")
```

Comment: Which one did you try and what **exactly** do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I Tried the first, it is giving me "Value"?

Comment: If you have a header row, adjust the formula to start below it.

Comment: I did, and now it is giving me "0" as a result.

Comment: What exactly is in column A? Dates,  or the month as text?

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((('Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$1000)=TEXT(TODAY();"MMMM"))*(LEFT('Sheet2'!$BC$2:$BC$1000)="X");'Sheet2'!$BD$2:$BD$1000)

Comment: Column A is monthame, november, decemeber etc. Column BC has X or Y in them, and BD has 0's or 1's

Comment: I have one last question. Everymonth new information is added to sheet2, but the old is not removed. Will the previous month (that is not "todays" month") be affected? Will all the information be removed?

Comment: I don't know what  you mean. If you *add* new data, the old data will remain; if you replace the old data, it won't. The formula will only look for months that match today's month, whatever that is.